# Inserting data into XML node with Xquery

Tags: xml, insert, xquery

I have a sample XML file and want to use Xquery to insert data into the nodes

```
<Employees>
<ID>1</ID>
<Company>Northwind Traders</Company>
<Last_x0020_Name>Freehafer</Last_x0020_Name>
<First_x0020_Name>Nancy</First_x0020_Name>
<E-mail_x0020_Address>nancy@northwindtraders.com</E-mail_x0020_Address>
<Job_x0020_Title>Sales Representative</Job_x0020_Title>
<Business_x0020_Phone>(123)555-0100</Business_x0020_Phone>
<Home_x0020_Phone>(123)555-0102</Home_x0020_Phone>
<Fax_x0020_Number>(123)555-0103</Fax_x0020_Number>
<Address>123 1st Avenue</Address>
<City>Seattle</City>
<State_x002F_Province>WA</State_x002F_Province>
<ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code>99999</ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code>
<Country_x002F_Region>USA</Country_x002F_Region>
<Web_x0020_Page>#http://northwindtraders.com#</Web_x0020_Page>
</Employees>
```

How would I be able to insert more XML below the current file for example:

```
<Employees>
<ID>2</ID>
<Company>Another Company</Company>
</Employees
```

I have tried the following but can't figure it out.

```
insert nodes <ID>2</ID> after 
doc("Employees.xml")//Employees
```

Comment: When you say you tried that `insert nodes`... did you get an error?  If so, what did it say?  Also, which XQuery processor (and do you know for sure that it supports XQuery Update syntax)?

Comment: I am using Saxon and I got an error message saying it didn't understand what insert nodes was. I Don't think it supports this function.

Comment: There are a number of editions of Saxon.  As stated on http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, only Saxon EE supports XQuery Update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert multiple nodes to xml field in single query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900479/insert-multiple-nodes-to-xml-field-in-single-query)